# How to tune garbage collector for unused images in GKE cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, garbage-collection, google-kubernetes-engine

I want to adjust garbage collector to autoclean images from nodes after 70% free space on node, so i need to descrease tresh hold for this because by default it's 85%

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/#kubelet-config-k8s-io-v1beta1-KubeletConfiguration

search on page "imageGCHighThresholdPercent"

i can't do than in google console in cluster or node-pools and i can't understand how to do this with terraform (which resource i should to use i don't know)

Answer (score 0):

The path of KubeletConfiguration is on the worker node at location /var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml but it is not recommended to change it.

GCP currently does not support changing “imageGCHighThresholdPercent” options but here are some [kubelet options](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-system-config#kubelet-options) you can set.

There are also plans to onboard more kubelet config options. However, no timeline is guaranteed.